# Filtering Django REST framework using IN operator

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I basically need something like `/?status=[active,processed]` or `/?status=active,processed`

My current setting is: `'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',)` and it's only filtering one value correctly (`/?status=active`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think there is no inbuilt functionality for that. But you can implement a custom filter to do that. This custom filter you can use in your filterset.

```
import django_filters as df

class InListFilter(df.Filter):
    """
    Expects a comma separated list
    filters values in list
    """
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value:
            return qs.filter(**{self.name+'__in': value.split(',')})
        return qs

class MyFilterSet(df.FilterSet):
    status = InListFilter(name='status')
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. One update though, instead of `self.name` it's now `self.field_name`. And for others wondering, this is how you add it to your view class: `filter_class = MyFilterSet`

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'field_in' when using Class.object.filter method.

```
class FileterdListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = FooSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_profile = self.kwargs['pk']
        if user_profile is not None:
            workers = Worker.objects.filter(user_profile = user_profile)
            queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(worker_in=(workers))
        else:
            return ''

        return queryset
```